# node.js seems not work in Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 3.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have installed **Ruby 1.8.7** and **Rails 3.1.0**.

When I do rails s this error is triggered.

```
alberto@alberto:~/screencast/tasks$ rails s
     /home/alberto/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@screencast/gems/execjs-2.1.0/lib/execjs.rb:2:in `require': /home/alberto/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-  2012.02@screencast/gems/execjs-2.1.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:22: syntax error, unexpected  ':', expecting ')' (SyntaxError)
      name:        "Node.js (V8)",
           ^
       /home/alberto/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@screencast/gems/execjs-2.1.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:22: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting kEND
      /home/alberto/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@screencast/gems/execjs-  2.1.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:23: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting kEND
     /home/alberto/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@screencast/gems/execjs-    2.1.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:24: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting kEND
/home/alberto/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@screencast/gems/execjs-2.1.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:26: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting kEND
     /home/alberto/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@screencast/gems/execjs-       2.1.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:29: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
      name:        "JavaScriptCore",
           ^
      /home/alberto/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@screencast/gems/execjs- 2.1.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:29: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting kEND
      /home/alberto/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@screencast/gems/execjs-  2.1.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:30: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting kEND
      /home/alberto/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@screencast/gems/execjs- 2.1.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:32: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting kEND
      /home/alberto/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@screencast/gems/execjs-  2.1.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:35: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
      name:        "SpiderMonkey",
           ^
```

Comment: PLEASE! Update your Ruby on Rails installation. You should be using Ruby 2.1.2 and Rails 4.1.0.

Comment: What happens is an old project. My version de node.js in this machine is v0.10.28
As I install node.js as a gem for a single proyect?  . I am using bundle and RVM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the source uses the new key-value syntax (`key: value`) rather than the older form (`:key => "value"`). You should update to Ruby 1.9 at a minimum. I suppose you can fix the source to use the older syntax, but I'd really recommend updating Ruby if possible.

Comment: thanks Alberto . You know how  I install node.js as a gem for a single proyect? . I am using bundle and RVM?

Comment: The gem is ruby source, and the version of ruby you are running doesn't support the syntax used in the gem's source. You'll either need to update your ruby, or edit the gem source. I strongly suggest trying a more modern version of ruby.